# What is -include in GNU Make and how it works?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

-include is used to ignore files which does not exist. But can anyone tell me where these files are used in this example?

```
CXX    := g++
TARGET := exec

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.d, $(SOURCES))

DEPFLAGS = -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)

all: $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(TARGET)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< $(DEPFLAGS)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by _where these files are used_ ...?  They are included by the include line, that's where they are used.

Comment: The reason putting the include first causes problems is that `make` with no argument always builds the first target; if you put the `include` before the `all` target then the first target in your makefile is the first target in the included file, not the `all` target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of this `Makefile` is a little questionable.

This is trying performing a variant of the technique discussed in the [Automatic Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) section of the Make manual, but it doesn't actually work as intended.

When you have an `include` statement, `make` will attempt to build any of the included files if they don't exist. Unfortunately, the `Makefile` doesn't have rules for generating the dependencies, which is why it has `-include` instead of just `include` -- the first time you run `make` it would fail to find the mentioned files.

Because the `Makefile` adds `$(DEPFLAGS)` to the command line used to generate `.o` files, the first time it compiles a `.o` file it will do so like this:

```
g++ -c somefile.c -MMD -MF somefile.d
```

The arguments in `$(DEPFLAGS)` ask `g++` to generate dependencies in `somefile.d`, so *next* time you run `make` it will use the dependencies file in its calculation.

The dependency information output by `-MMD` will be a series of `make` rules that look something like this (assuming that `file1.cpp` includes `file2.h`):

```
file1.o: file1.cpp file2.h
```

A fixed `Makefile` might look something like this:

```
CXX := g++
TARGET := exec

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPENDS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)

%.d: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -M -MMD $<

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(TARGET)

include $(DEPENDS)
```

Here we're relying on `make`'s implicit rules for compiling `.cpp` files to `.o` files, and we introduce a pattern rule for building `.d` files from `.cpp` files.

This allows us to remove the `-` from `-include`, because when `make`
first runs it will see that the dependency files are missing, and will
use the pattern rule to build them.

Comment: You don't really need the rebuild include file feature for proper operation of dependency generation.  See the model suggested here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: It looks as if maybe that's what the Makefile as posted in the question was trying to do. That's an interesting idea, but reading through it I'm not sure it's a better solution. This seems pretty simple and deals well with missing dependency files.

Comment: If you rename or remove some prerequisite file, like `foo.h`, this system will require a `clean` operation to avoid make failures.  Also, this method is definitely less efficient; for a small environment it's not so bad but for a large environment it's certainly noticeable.

Comment: I find original approach better (to have dependency files generated as a byproduct of a compilation). When you compile the code first time, it does not matter that you don't have dependency files, since you don't have object files as well and need to compile anyway. Dependencies are only useful for recompile. Therefore unless some of your dependencies are not autogenerated, I find this additional pass of `-M` a waste of time, particularly heavy in case of C++. In each approach I would also use `-MP` to avoid situation where a previously used header is removed and you cannot recompile.